# req.flash() not working after req.session.destroy()

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, flash-message

Based on a condition, I need to destroy user's current session, and redirect him to a login page with a message. I use `flash` to have a show-once-only message. Everywhere, this works fine on my app except here, because here I use `req.flash` after `req.session.destroy()`.

How can I achieve this? I have tried placing `req.flash()` before `req.session.destroy()` but that does not work, I think because `req.session.destroy()` clears the session where we just stored the flash message. Thanks.

```
   if( req.session.adminUser.blocked ){
        req.logout();
        req.session.destroy(()=>{
            req.flash("flashMessage", "You are blocked, Please contact admin");
            req.session.save(function(){
                res.redirect("/admin-panel/login");
                return false;
            });//session.save()
        });
    }
```

With this code, I get this error - `Error: req.flash() requires sessions`. If I move the flash statement before the `session.destroy` statement, then I do not get any error, but the message is not shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.flash()` depends on a valid session, so if you destroy that session, the flash messages are destroyed as well.

It seems to me that it might actually be better to create a separate "blocked" page, and render that, instead of redirecting the blocked used back to the login page (where they can't log in anyway):

```
req.session.save(function(){
  res.render("/admin-panel/blocked");
});
```

As a (less-pretty) alternative, you can pass a query string to the login page indicating that the user was blocked:

```
res.redirect("/admin-panel/login?blocked=true");
```

And use a check in the login-template to see if it should show a "you are blocked" message.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your both alternatives seem pretty well to me. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [flash source](https://github.com/expressjs/flash/blob/master/index.js) you can see that this middleware **REQUIRE** session to work

Comment: Thanks. But I know this and I have already been using session. And as I mentioned it works fine everywhere in my app. The problem is that it does not work in the callback after calling `req.session.destroy()`.

Comment: After you call `req.session.destroy()` there in no `session` to be used by `flash` so how you expect it to work?

Comment: Is there some way to make this work? You understand my requirement? If a user is blocked, I need to log them out by destroying their session, then redirect them back to login screen. But with a flash message, that you have been blocked.

Comment: You can implement similar mechanism that uses for example `cookies`, but with `flash` you can't because it's REQUIRE SESSION

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old post by now, but in case it helps someone.

It looks like using `req.logout();` does the trick, this allows `req.flash();` to be called afterwards effectively.

```
"Node version": "14.16.1"
"express": "4.17.2"
"express-session": "1.17.2"
"passport": "0.5.2"
"connect-flash": "0.1.1"
"cookie-parser": "1.4.6"
```